# Выдаёт ошибку Notice: Undefined variable:

Tags: php

```
<?php
session_start();
include("url");#Тут подключаюсь к БД
$class=$_GET['class'];
$dictant_from_bd = mysqli_query( $mysqli, "SELECT `audio` FROM `dictations` WHERE class='$class'"); 
while($dictants_arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dictant_from_bd)) { 
$dic[] = $dictants_arr['audio']; 
}
$col=1;
$num=1;
for ($i=0; $i<$col; $i++) {
echo $dic[$i];} #здесь возникает лажа
?>
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

> Notice: Undefined variable: dic in
>   /home/v/vladle43/muzikalka-onlayn.rf/public_html/all/dictant/class.php
>   on line 12

Подскажите как исправить

Comment: Первым делом, советую научится пользоваться PDO, и вместо сессий самому работать с куками.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Раз вопрос только о `notice`, то здесь дело в том, что Вы пытаетесь добавить элементы в массив, которого пока не существует:

```
$dic[] = $dictants_arr['audio'];
```

Да, `PHP` позволяет на лету создавать переменные без предварительного объявления, но в данном случае Вы не создаете новую переменную, а пытаетесь к ней обратиться `[]`, что закономерно приводит к замечанию.

Чтобы это решить, в данном случае достаточно перед циклом объявить свой массив:

```
$dic = array();

while($dictants_arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dictant_from_bd)) { 
    $dic[] = $dictants_arr['audio']; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Вставьте строчку `$dic = Array();` после `$class=`.

А еще, похоже, что у Вас запрос возвращает 0 строчек... посмотрите.

Answer (score 1):

```
session_start();
include("url");//Тут подключаюсь к БД

//избежим ошибки notice если GET не передана и сразу экранируем данные
$class = isset($_GET['class'])
    ? $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['class'])
    : '';

$query =  "SELECT `audio` FROM `dictations` WHERE class='$class'";
//выдадим ошибку если запрос не сработает
if (!$result = $mysqli->query($query)) die($mysqli->error);

if ($result->num_rows==0) echo 'Записей нет'; //на случай, если в базе ничего нет
else {
    $while ($row = $result_fetch_assoc()){
        echo $row['audio'];
    }   
}
```